# I have two JQuery Ajax API calls to a REST API, one doesn't work why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I'm doing a get REST api request to a server. The server houses automation jobs what I'm looking to kick off with parameters.

```
var jobURL = "https://hostname/api/v1/tasks"; 

$.ajax({
    url: jobURL,
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        name: '*JOBNAME*'
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ obj.access_token,
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Accept:'application/json'
    },
    success: function(data){
        taskname_obj = data    // result
}
```

I'm doing this per the documentation of the server product and it is working.

I have a successful request, with items returned in the 'taskname_obj' variable.
With that said I'm trying to use the same sort of code for another call.

```
// THIS IS WORKING TO JOB WITHOUT PARAMS.

        // Let's run the job. 
        $.ajax({
            url: jobURL,
            method: 'POST',
            async: false,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ obj.access_token
            },
            success: function(data){
                taskname_obj2 = data    // result
            }
        })
```

SO I'm doing the above code

Again I am success, I can start my job. I have indication of success returned into `taskname_obj2`.

With all that said, I am trying to start this with parameters. I suppose I have to put that into the "data:" item, and I shout use JSON. So... I do the following...

```
var payload = { 
    USER_ID: "",
    BEGDATE: "060121",
    ENDDATE: "121521"
};

$.ajax({
    url: jobURL,
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: payload,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ obj.access_token,
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Accept:'application/json'
    },
    success: function(data){
        taskname_obj2 = data    // result
    }
})
```

This doesn't work. I am getting a 415 error back from the server for unsupported media type. I also tried not using JSON.stringify for the data item but I also get a 415 with that.

I think I'm not telling it correctly how to read my JSON. Can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried adding this `contentType: 'application/json',` to no avail.

**UPDATE:**
Using BARMARs technique returns me a 422 error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: jobURL,
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ obj.access_token
    },
    success: function(data){
        taskname_obj2 = data    // result
    }
})
```

Comment: You don't need `content-type` for GET requests, since it doesn't send any contents.

Comment: In the POST request, Why are you using `JSON.stringify(payload)` when it's supposed to be URL-encoded?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, I don't do jquery all the time. I'm trying to translate a powershell into jquery for a chrome extension. Thanks about the tip on the get request, I removed that and that does work. The problem child is the POST, which I removed the stringify from. Thanks for that too

Comment: @Barmar The GET request contains `data`. Isn't that sent as a body?

Comment: @jabaa No it doesn't. The `data:` values are sent as query parameters in the URL.

Comment: I'm still getting 415 with the updates. I don't understand it I'm afraid

Comment: `async: false` should never ever be used. It is a horrible practice and has been deprecated for years by browser vendors. You should be seeing such deprecation warning in dev tools console

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `Content-type` and `Accept` headers. Use the `contentType:` and `dataType:` options to specify these.

And since the API requires JSON input, it should be `contentType: "application/json"`

```
$.ajax({
    url: jobURL,
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ obj.access_token
    },
    success: function(data){
        taskname_obj2 = data    // result
    }
})
```

Comment: The parameters are supposed to be `taskId` and `params`. Why are you sending `USER_ID`, `BEGDATE`, and `ENDDATE`?

Comment: Are those supposed to be the values in `params`? You need an object like `{taskId: xxx, params: {USER_ID: "", BEGDATE: "060121", ENDDATE: "121521"}}`

Comment: The task ID goes into the URL. the params are whatever I'm sending as a hashtable in my powershell script. I could post that script which does work if that would help to answer that question

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see the response body, I think there should be more details about the validation error there.

Comment: `{"status":422,"errors":[{"message":"Param name/value pairs cannot be empty"}]}`, I'm doing those params like that because in powershell it works like this `$taskparms = @{"USER_ID" = "ABCUSERID"} | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: I can't see a reason for that. Do you see the JSON being sent in the Network tab?

Comment: I do see it under 'request payload': `{ "USER_ID": "", "BEGDATE": "060121", "ENDDATE": "121521" }`

Comment: Then I really don't know why the API is saying that it's empty.